# Prerequisites for Hilbert Cohn-Vossen's Geometry and the Imagination?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I've not read this book(not really),but I would like to know how much is assumed by the reader.
can I recommend this to the layperson?
Also ,any more recent similar books?

I already know of Courant ad Polya's books.

Answer (score 1):

Hilbert's book is based on lectures that were intended for laymen and according to his own preface most of what's in there is elementary.  That doesn't mean it's super-easy, though.  And it's definitely not the right book for persons who don't like formulas or don't like to think.

More recent books (although also quite old by now) would be the ones by Coxeter, starting with "Introduction to Geometry".

Also, I haven't read it yet, but I would take a look at "The Four Pillars of Geometry" by Stillwell.  I think he's a great author.